# Google in-app billing library isn't showing in SDK Mananger

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently downloaded and installed Eclipse Java EE IDE: . I made a simple application that runs well on my device ; now I want to publish the app .

I am not able to see the in-app billing library in the extras section of the sdk manager.

I was told it was found in the SDK manager under "Extras". I proceeded in Eclipse to Window > Android SDK Manger. I waited for it get done fetching and then went to "Extras". Making sure "Updates/New" was checked as well as "Installed"; however, under the "Extras" tab is "Android Support Package" , "Google Play service" , "Google USB driver", "Intel emulator" and in-app billing library is missing .

And so here I am ... stuck on what I need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think it is important to installed it. you can simply put the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` or `TrivialDrive` sample on following dir `<sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/`. This should be work

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Android sdk tools using sdk manager
Click help - > check for updates in eclipse
open the sdk manager again
Now shows all the packages...